# hook a process and get files it`s created\deleted\renamed

Tags: c#, c++, hook, filesystemwatcher, file-watcher

I have created a c# program which gets new loaded process

```
startWatch.EventArrived += new ventArrivedEventHandler(startWatch_EventArrived);
```

and doing stuff when eventHandler fire.

afterwards im  using:

```
foreach (var runningProcess in Process.GetProcessesByName(ShortProcessName))
```

to get runningProcess.MainModule data for the current process
and after that

```
foreach (System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule module in MYPROCESS.Modules)
```

to get list of child process and modules.

My next wish is to get an output of files which created \ deleted \ renamed \ changed \ whatever by the process i catched.
I have tried digging the 'Process' constructure and modules but didnt find anything for that. I also tried using filewatcher, but also here cannot get you the parent process responsible for file changes.
i guess this cannot be done using high level language such as c# but lower.

Unfortunatly im not familiar with lowers. in the end i want a service \ watcher to hook a process real-time and create an output (file) of which file he has been messing with.

hope someone save my day :)
Thanks!

Comment: Seems, you want a virtual machine (good luck)

Comment: Why do you want this information (it looks like an XY Problem)? And by "lowers" do you mean drivers?

Comment: XY problem?
think the process is a malware... i want to know which file the malware created or deleted. lowers means for low coding languages such as assembly, c, c++